# Algorithm to Tile Window

Tags: c#, window

I've a Form with 2 buttons:

1. Open a new Form, and put it in a List
2. Tile the opened Form

What I need to do now is to write an algorithm that maximizes the user screen occupied by forms. Obviously this would be simple, so I have some extra requirement:

1. width / height ratio must be in a given interval, say [a,b]
2. Window may be overlapped by V pixel "vertically" and H pixel "horizontally"

Edit : since it seemed not clear, here's the code...

```
        public static List<Form> formlist = new List<Form>();
        ...

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form f = new Form();
            f.Text = "Title";
            ...
            formlist.Add(f);
            f.Show();
         }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             foreach(Form f in formlist)
             {
                    f.Width =  *** opt width ***;
                    f.Height = *** opt height ***;
                    f.SetDesktopLocation( ***opt x***,*** opt y***);
             }
        }
```

Comment: 3. Would you like also a beer with fries?

Comment: Please do not put tags in the title.

Comment: Oh, as a side note, let's say screen width is W and height is H

Comment: Not enough constraints.  This is *not* a usable user interface, create *one* form, tile its contents.

Comment: @ Andrzej Nosal: I dont' need anybody to write the algorithm for me. I just need to know if someone knows such an algorithm.

Comment: @ Hans Passant : I'm sorry, I can't understand what you're suggesting. I've only 1 main form, that pops up other forms... what's the problem? and why this is not a usable interface?

Comment: @ What do you mean by `Open a new Form, and put it in a List` What kind of list?

Comment: edited and added some code to the first post; I hope that now it's more clear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have written down your question unambiguously, you may already know the answer (chances are that you will, as arranging a few rectangles on screen is typically a trivial matter). If not, then you will at least have explained to the reader what it is you wish them to answer for you.

So, try to write the question...

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't. And I hope that now the question is not ambigous... But I'll try to reforumlate: does a not NP algorithm exist to solve a generalized Knapsack problem with those constraints?

Comment: Your question doesn't make anything very clear (except that you wish to position some windows somewhere "optimally"). However, your comment mentions Knapsack problems. Is that relevant information that should perhaps be in your question? In light of these edits, I'll also edit my answer...

Comment: Let's try with an example :) Have you ever played online poker? I need to tile frames just like like fulltilt or pokerstar software do with poker tables.

Comment: All I've understood so far is that you wish to "arrange *n* forms in a rectangular grid", (though "knapsack" alludes to some form of weighting). So my answer is still: Try describing your design. Don't point at examples, but try to write down in plain English the design of how the tiling works. Do this clearly and you will gain a much better understanding of exactly what you need to do, and what the question is you need to ask on SO to get help.

Comment: @kaharas Are you trying to say that you want to arrange/resize forms like bunch of cards?

Comment: No :) I want to put tables like this : http://i467.photobucket.com/albums/rr35/jdizzzle72/12tables.jpg , respecting frame proportion in both 4:3 and 16:9 monitors, and with a user-defined maximum overlap.

Comment: @kaharas: That is simply a rectangular grid, except that the grid size is the size of the window contents (so the borders and titlebar of the window lie outside the grid rectangle). As for respecting the aspect ratio, you simply have to fit the largest rectangle of a fixed aspect ratio that you can into the screen's width/height - this simply means cropping either the width or the height as appropriate.